# TCP Client Python Error, Document has moved or Bad request

Tags: python, tcp

I am creating a basic TCP Client script and am having trouble with it when I run it.

Code:

```
import socket

target_host = input("What is the target host? ")
target_port = input("What is the target port? ")

host = (target_host[4:])

#create the socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connect the client
client.connect((target_host, target_port))

#send
data = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host + "\r\n\r\n"
client.send(data.encode("utf-8"))

#receive data
response = client.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")

print(response)
```

When I run it I always receive a bad request or "page has moved". Here is results for when I ran it for www.google.com at port 80.

```
What is the target host? "www.google.com"
What is the target port? 80
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 20:30:34 GMT
Expires: Wed, 07 Mar 2018 20:30:34 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

How can I not land on a bad request or "document has moved" page?

Thank you!

Comment: Aside: unless your intent is purely academic, use one of the existing well-written robust easy-to-use HTTP clients. I prefer [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: *"TCP Client Python Error,...."* - neither "document has moved" nor "bad request" are errors at the TCP level. And the first one is not even an error but an instruction where to look. I recommend that you get a better understanding of how HTTP works before attempting to write a HTTP client by your own instead of using some established HTTP library. Standards exist to be followed and not to be ignored and then wondering why it does not work as expected.

Comment: Ok so how do I do it for https and hsts sites?